# Recovery Pending Issue

Tags: sql-server-2014

one of my database is under recover pending issue since yesterday ... am trying to solve it but am unable to do so .. Please please help me

**tried this**

```
Exec Sp_resetstatus database;
Alter Database database Set Emergency 
DBCC CheckDB(database)
Alter Database database Set Single_user with rollback immediate
dbcc checkDB (database,repair_allow_data_loss)
alter database database set multi_user
```

**but am getting this error**

> The suspect flag on the database "DATABASE" is already reset. Msg
>   5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database
>   'DATABASE'. Try again later. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 ALTER
>   DATABASE statement failed. Msg 945, Level 14, State 2, Line 3 Database
>   'DATABASE' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient
>   memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.

Please help me guys

Comment: >>>See the SQL Server errorlog for details<<< Even server says you what should you check. Please check the errorlog and update your question with information from errorlog

Comment: Did you check that the Database files are present? Looks like either a data or log file is not acessible by the engine, or it is simply not there. Also dbcc checkDB (database,repair_allow_data_loss) is not to be handled carelessly, It ignores things like constraints, and will leave your data in an inconsistent state.

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/02/sql-server-fix-error-945-database-cannot-be-opened-due-to-inaccessible-files-or-insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-see-the-sql-server-error-log-for-details/